# document.images creating a list where only the first element is valid

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

Have been tinkering away with phantomJS and have come across something i dont understand. I can see the number of photos but can only see the first object

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger'

page.open(address,function(status){

    page.render('page.png');

    if(status=="success"){
        var title = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.title;
        });
        console.log('Page title is ' + title);

        var imgs = page.evaluate(function() {
           return document.images;
        });
        console.log(imgs.length);
        console.log(imgs[0]);
        console.log(imgs[1]);
    }
    phantom.exit();
})
```

the output of this is:

```
Page title is Tiger - ....
95
[object Object]
null
```

Any idea why the only the 1st object is listed?

Comment: Do a `console.dir(imgs)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(imgs, null, 2))` to get a better understanding of the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html),

> The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a
>   simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized
>   via JSON, then it is fine. Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will
>   not work!

So, in your case, do not return img elements directly because it will not work. `imgs` is not a list of images but a list of list of DOM elements.

A very simple way to solve this could be

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger'

page.open(address,function(status){

    page.render('page.png');

    if(status=="success"){
        var title = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.title;
        });
        console.log('Page title is ' + title);


        var imgs = page.evaluate(function() {
            return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'), function (img) {
                return img.getAttribute('src');
            });
        });
        console.log(imgs.length);
        console.log(imgs[0]);
        console.log(imgs[1]);
    }
    phantom.exit();
})
```